# Make Our Android Application work As a Preinstalled Application

Tags: android

I want to make my own application as a preinstalled android application.

To accompolish this 
I tried to push in my app apk in `/system/app` folder but could not able to do. First i mounted `r/w` permission for `/system/app` folder using `adb shell` commands but that also i am not able to do.
Is anyone have ideas.

how to solve this issue?

Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: `adb install my_app.apk`?

Comment: There are apps that allow you to do this.  Titanium Backup allows you to move installed apps in and out of /system/app/.  You might consider looking at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First of all you must root your phone to do that !**

Now You are trying to pack your app as system application. classes.dex files are ripped from system applications and saved as optimized ODEX files. So before setting up, you should convert APK files to DEX to ODEX and then put it in system folder.

> You can get more information about ODEX/DEX [here.](http://www.alliance-rom.com/community/wiki/odex-and-deodex/)

You can directly install apk by adding them into system/app folder after gaining the root access on device. ODEX files would be best choice for developing system apps. **Samsung, htc and many more companies** use it to deliver their custom pre-installed apps.